# omnet++: artery framework usage

Tags: frameworks, omnet++

I am starting with Artery, while I already did some OMNET++ work some time ago. I have 3 very short questions :)

1. The first thing I notice, as far as I understand, is that Artery
   builds using cmake. So, to build it, every time I must switch to a
   console, am I right? In fact, it builds ok for me.
2. However, this prevents me from debugging in OMNET++, am I right? I
   know I can debug in console using gdb.
3. Finally, it seems the omnetpp.ini does not recognize several of its
   entries, even if it considers them when running make run_example!
   Please see the following image. This, of course, is unconvenient
   since it disables the code completion for omnetpp.ini and it's
   unpractical to see if the syntax the changes I want to apply to the
   simulation are ok.

[image: view]

So, please tell me if my assumptions in 1 and 2 are right and also how can I see my entries in omnetpp.ini recognized as in question 3! :)

Have a really nice day!

Comment: I think you can reconfigure OMNeT++ to use `cmake`, but it's probably a non-trivial task. [There is some discussion about making cmake default on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/54HLIfCZKco), but I'm not sure whether all features discussed there made it to the 5.x release.

Comment: Regarding 3, I believe that's a general issue with the *.name notation in OMNeT++ (at least, I've never seen that work correctly before, though I don't really use the IDE personally).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your experience! Let's see if I can get more information for the other questions! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I ask cannot be done so I will consider this solved :)